# angular route animation change dynamically

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I want to change route animation dynamically. I have 4 animations in app.component.ts when I click button I will get some value of animation type according that I will change animation. For example if I am getting 1 I will apply slideLeft, if 2 will apply slideRight and so on. But....
but I am unable to change route animation dynamically. I am updating animation array but I think angular router taking animation value at first time only. after that even if value of currentAnimation is changed it will not update animation.

**My app.component.ts**

```
import { ComponentsModelService } from './components-model.service';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, NavigationStart } from "@angular/router";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import { Component, Directive,HostBinding, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {trigger, query, transition, style, animate, state, group} from '@angular/animations';


const slideToRight = [
    query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 }),{ optional: true }),
    query(':leave', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),{ optional: true }),
    group([
        query(':leave', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' })),
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })),
        ],{ optional: true })
    ])
];

const slideToLeft = [
    query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 }),{ optional: true }),
    query(':leave', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),{ optional: true }),
    group([
        query(':leave', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })),
        ],{ optional: true })
    ])
];

const slideToTop = [
    query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 }),{ optional: true }),
    query(':leave', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }), { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)' }),{ optional: true }),
    group([
        query(':leave', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' })),
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' })),
        ],{ optional: true })
    ])
];

const slideToBottom = [
    query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 }),{ optional: true }),
    query(':leave', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }), { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }),{ optional: true }),
    group([
        query(':leave', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)' })),
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' })),
        ],{ optional: true })
    ])
];

var currrentAnimation = slideToTop;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('routeTransition', [
            transition("* => *", currrentAnimation)
        ])
    ]
})

export class AppComponent {
    ios: boolean;
    iosClass: string = "";
    previousUrl: string: "";
    count: number = 1;
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        console.log("in contrcutore");
        this.ios = !!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);
        if(this.ios == true) {
            this.iosClass = "ios";
        }
    }
    getState(outlet) {
       return outlet.activatedRouteData.state;
    }
    changeAnimation(){

        /* Changing animation object here but it is not working */
        console.log("button clicked2222222222");
        currrentAnimation = slideToRight;
        var navigateToPage = "page3";
        this.router.navigate([navigateToPage]);
    }
};
```

**app.component.html**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100i" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- use the font -->
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
}
html, body,
main {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

</style>
<main [@routeTransition]="getState(o)">
    <router-outlet  #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
<button (click) ="changeAnimation()">Change Animation</button>
```

Now on changeAnimation I am updating currentAnimation to slideToRight but on route change slideToTop is working.
I am unable to understand why changeAnimation not changing animation.

**Update: I solved it**

Dynamically updating animation array will not solve problem.
Before Answering you need to underunderstand how angular route animation works.

1- transition("* => *", currrentAnimation) you see * => * means if you have two routes let us say 'route1' and 'route2' then * will indicate any of them like 'route1 => route2' and *will apply animation if the routes are different *(note this). 'route1' and 'route2' variable are being calculated in getState function:

```
getState(outlet) {
           return outlet.activatedRouteData.state;
        }
```

So whatever we are returning from here will matched to route 'source => destination' destination variables.
So what if i can change destination variable.

2- So I thought If I declare a varible for [@routeTransition] = "myVarible" and will update it they it should work.But it did't worked. I don't know why.

3- So I created a common service for setting and getting animation name.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {trigger, query, transition, style, animate, state, group} from '@angular/animations';

@Injectable()
export class AnimationControllerService {

  currentAnimation: any = null;
  currentAnimationId: number = -1;
  public animations: any;
  constructor() {

  }
  setCurrentAnimation(animationId) {
    var nextAnimation = "";
    var isDuplicate = false;

    switch(animationId) {
        case 1:
            nextAnimation = "slideToLeft";
            break;
        case 2:
            nextAnimation = "slideToRight";
            break;
        case 3:
            nextAnimation = "slideToTop";
            break;
        case 4:
            nextAnimation = "slideToBottom";
            break;
    }
    if(this.currentAnimation && (this.currentAnimation.indexOf("Duplicate") > -1)) {
        isDuplicate = true;
    }

    /* add duplicate if previous animation otherwise animation will not work */
    if((animationId == this.currentAnimationId) && !isDuplicate) {
        nextAnimation = nextAnimation + "Duplicate";
    }
    this.currentAnimation = nextAnimation;
    this.currentAnimationId = animationId;
  }
  getCurrentAnimation() {
    return this.currentAnimation;
  }
}
```

As you can see I am setting duplicate animation name because I my previous animation was slideLeft and I again want slideLeft then it will not work because "* => *" work if it get different parameters.

4- Now in app.component.html

```
<main [@routeTransition]="getAnimation()">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

5- Now app.component.ts looks like

```
import { AnimationControllerService } from './animationcontroller.service';
import { Component, Directive,HostBinding, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import {trigger, query, transition, style, animate, state, group} from '@angular/animations';

const slideToRight = // animation code same as question
const slideToLeft = // animation code same as question

const slideToTop =// animation code same as question

const slideToBottom = // animation code same as question


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('routeTransition', [
            transition("* => slideToLeft", slideToLeft),
            transition("* => slideToRight", slideToRight),
            transition("* => slideToTop", slideToTop),
            transition("* => slideToBottom", slideToBottom),
            transition("* => slideToLeftDuplicate", slideToLeft),
            transition("* => slideToRightDuplicate", slideToRight),
            transition("* => slideToTopDuplicate", slideToTop),
            transition("* => slideToBottomDuplicate", slideToBottom),
        ])
    ],
})

export class AppComponent {
    ios: boolean;
    iosClass: string = "";
    constructor(private animService: AnimationControllerService) {

    }
    getAnimation() {
        return this.animService.getCurrentAnimation();
    }
};
```

6 - Now you can easily navigate to any route by simple injecting to your class and setting current animation and then navigate to your route. So simple

```
this.animService.setCurrentAnimation(1);
this.router.navigate([navigateToPage]);
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: yes, I have updated question with solution.

Comment: Nice, I came up with sort of similar approach and linked to this stackoverflow for further reading about duplicate “issue”. My solution is here: https://medium.com/@perjansson/angular-dynamic-page-transitions-for-better-ux-8435077c26cc?source=linkShare-de8169c1a861-1527252330

Comment: This solution worked really well for me, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Do you have working example? I'm using angular 11, neither approach work. Route animation only triggered only if I return outlet.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path.

Comment: This is working solution. Not sure about angular 11 but you can try it and take similar approach in angular 11 if not working. Please check how angular route animation works given in solution.